# store a queryset in the session with django

Tags: python, django, session, django-queryset, pagination

I have problem storing a big queryset in the session. This queryset is from a search and I need to store it for paginate inside every result. This is the code in my view:

```
c = queryset.order_by('-order') 
request.session['query_search'] = c
```

You can see an example in my site: http://www.lukmi.com/escorts/barcelona/
This is a list of results(the queryset) and I store it in the session because I need to use it in each profile to go to next profile.

I have some problems to store it because is very big. Anybody knows a good solution?

Answer (score 4):

You could store only the list of PKs and then query through them when you need to.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently developing a very similar site to yours also in Django.
I stored the queryset in cache, where cache key is an urlencoded string of search parameters- this way if someone performs identical search it doesn't have to repeat the expensive queries to get the same results.

In your case, you can generate parameters list from url.

```
 form = form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        persons = .... #expensive queries that fetch the results of search

        cache_id = urlencode(cd.items())
        #create md5 hash to use in link to results
        cache_id = hashlib.md5(cache_id).hexdigest()
        cache.set(cache_id, persons, CACHE_TIMEOUT)

        #also store form data in cache, so the form can be easily reconstructed from cache id
        cache.set(cache_id+'_form', request.POST, CACHE_TIMEOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or may you can store the sql generated by the query and then execute.

```
request.session['query_search'] = c.query.as_sql()
```

Comment: The problem with doing it this way is that the query results may change from page to page.

Answer (score 0):

Big sessions eat ressources (I suppose Django makes no exception to this).
Make it a JSON list, then use the user's browser local storage : http://jstorage.info , a jQuery plugin, cross-browser.
You'll need a way to tell if the data is outdated (checksum? did not find the solution yet) to get back to the server and ask for a new JSON var in the template.